# Custom Entity Naming Rule for EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have an edmx file in my Visual Studio project, when you insert a table from from your model into the edmx, it gets the same name as in the Database, for example, by importing `myTable` you get an entity called `myTable` with Set Name `myTables`.

How can I make the tables adhere to a custom naming convention when adding them to my file? So, for example, adding `myTable` results in an entity called `tblmyTable` with Set Name `tblmyTables`.

Comment: Dear downvoter... when you downvote a question try and leave a comment explaining why the downvote, I think my question is clear enough however short, if you need further explanation I can clarify it for you... IF you leave a comment with your doubts.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but it's not clear to me what you want to do. Do you mean using a custom naming convention when generating the code files?

Comment: Updated it... hope that's clear enough.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970225/when-i-generate-the-ddl-from-an-entity-framework-4-0-model-can-i-change-how-it-n) then

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using a custom T4 template, but these files are big... I need to know how to modify that file in order for it to custom name the classes.

Comment: I know how to do this, but since it is such a horrible violation of the framework design guidelines (polish notation????  camelCase type names???) I refuse to answer.  Well, actually, I don't know how to do this, but I'd rather hit myself in the head with a rubber mallet than do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If you are using the old Entity Object generator EF4.0 or EF5.0:

You need to modify the **`<YourModelName>.tt`** file in multiple places.

The template calls `container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()` to get all your entity sets where the returned `EntityeSet.ElementType` (Where the type of `ElementType` is `EntityType`) contains the information about your entities.

These objects are used in many places in the template so the easiest solution would be to set the `Name` property of the `EntityType`. However the `Name` property is internal so you need to use refection to set it.

So locate the following line in your template around **line 163**:

```
region.Begin(CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_RegionObjectSetProperties"));
foreach (EntitySet set in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
```

And you need to add here the following code to set the `Name` property:

```
region.Begin(CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_RegionObjectSetProperties"));
foreach (EntitySet set in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
      set.ElementType.GetType()
            .GetProperty("Name", 
               BindingFlags.Instance | 
               BindingFlags.Public | 
               BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
               BindingFlags.SetProperty)
         .SetValue(set.ElementType, "tbl" + set.ElementType.Name, null);
```

Sadly you are not done yet because you still have to change two places:

First the generated property names are not fixed so you need to locate the following line around line **line 173**:

```
<#=code.SpaceAfter(NewModifier(set))#><#=Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(set)#> ObjectSet<<#=MultiSchemaEscape(set.ElementType, code)#>> <#=code.Escape(set)#>
```

And change it to (Add the `tbl` before `<#=code.Escape(set)#>`:

```
<#=code.SpaceAfter(NewModifier(set))#><#=Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(set)#> ObjectSet<<#=MultiSchemaEscape(set.ElementType, code)#>> tbl<#=code.Escape(set)#>
```

Because of the reflection hack you need to remove the "tbl" prefix form the generated `EdmEntityTypeAttribute` so you need to locate the following line around **line 295**:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="<#=entity.NamespaceName#>", Name="<#=entity.Name#>")]
```

And change it to:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="<#=entity.NamespaceName#>", Name="<#=entity.Name.Replace("tbl","")#>")]
```

### If you are using the default EF DbContext generator EF5.0 or EF6.0 with edmx:

You need to modify the `tt` files to apply your custom naming convention.

First you should modify the **`<YourEdmxName>.tt`** file:

Around **line 23** you should locate the following method call:

```
fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
```

This method crates your entity classes so if you want to modify the generated file names you need to change it to:

```
fileManager.StartNewFile("tbl" + entity.Name + ".cs");
```

Then around **line 307** you need to find the following method declaration:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
}
```

This methods writes your class names so here you need to change it to apply your convention:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        "tbl" + _code.Escape(entity), // add tbl prefix before the entity name
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
}
```

Finally you need to modify your **`<YourEdmxName>.Context.tt`**:

Around **line 296** you need to locate the following method which write out the `DbSet` properties:

```
public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
        _code.Escape(entitySet));
}
```

And change it again to apply your convention:

```
public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
        // add "tbl" to the type name DbSet<Table> -> DbSet<tblTable>
        "tbl" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType), 
        // add "tbl" to property name Tables -> tblTables
        "tbl" + _code.Escape(entitySet));
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to go around this for days. I don't know if maybe the EF is different or something but I can't get it working... I'm using EF v4.0, is that the same your answer was wrote for?

Comment: @PedroC88 yeah, I've assumed EF5.0 or above.... Which EF4 tt are you using the POCO, Self Tracking or, object EntityObject? Can you maybe upload your current tt file somewhere and post a link here?

Comment: I can't upload the file, how can I know the type of tt I'm using?

Comment: @PedroC88 how are the generated classes looks like? Do you have a `SomethingContainer` which derives from `ObjectContext` and your entities are deriving from `EntityObject` and having some `EdmEntityTypeAttribute`?

Comment: Only 5 minutes left so I awarded the points since you're obviously on the right track. I made all the new changes but still not working, I'm trying to make it work though. Will post back.

Comment: OK, I got this part working but one last thing, although the classes are generating correctly, the name of the EntityType and its set name aren't still changing in the .edmx designer and I need them to, How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way to make this changes also in the .edmx designer. My only idea is to change the source code of Entity Framework but this version of EF is not open source... So your only option is to rename all of your entities in the .edmx **by hand** however in this case you don't need to change the `tt` template because they are reading the .edmx.